# One @StreamListener depending on another @StreamListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a use case where I have 2 topics in Kafka , one topic is ABC and the other topic is CDE , the data in topic in CDE is used in computation and its not much large in size so we want to fill in memory Map with this data , and then using this Map in computations with data from topic ABC . So as of step 1 when the component starts I want to fill up the Map with all data in CDE before consuming any message from ABC and while doing any processing on data received from topic ABC , I will check if there is un consumed message in topic CDE if yes then update cache , and use cache results. How can this be achieved using Spring Cloud Stream

Answer (score 0):

This is really not the case for spring-cloud-stream. Filling up the cache is the responsibility of the initialization/startup, so it's not really a question of how it can be achieved with spring-cloud-stream, rather how it can be achieved. 
I mean of course you can hack something up using spring-cloud-stream, all I am saying is that it was not designed use case where a listener will have to load some cache.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge , so I would rephrase the question on what is the best way to maintain cache for this kind of scenario ?

Comment: There are many caching systems and technologies out there, and even though it's out of scope of this channel, there are channels on this forum that may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caching